# Is there any differences between "there is no way to do something" & "That's no way to do something"?

Tags: word-usage

See these sentences

"**There is no way to speak to her**" & "**That's no way to speak to her**".

*Are they the same or different?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're different.

"There is no way to speak to her" implies that it is impossible to speak to her. No matter how much you may want to, it won't happen.

"That's no way to speak to her" is discussing the manner of speaking to her. It means that whatever-you-just-said is inappropriate or offensive.

As examples:

---

"Hey, are you able to get in touch with Janet?"

"No, her phone's off and I don't know where she is. **There's no way to speak to her**"

---

"Hey, Janet, you idiot! You forgot your phone!"

"Hey! **That's no way to speak to her!** Mind your manners!"

Comment: so, does "<b>That's no way to speak to her</b>"="<b>That's not the right way to speak to her</b>"?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. It's a bit narrower in meaning, but the idea's the same.