# What's the difference in meaning between "I don't see a way" and "there is no way"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

What does it means? Is there a difference? What is the sentence meaning?

> The thing is, it never gets easier between us and it all keeps starting again and I **don't see a way** to do this.

Vs.

> The thing is, it never gets easier between us and it all keeps starting again and **there is no way** to do this.

Comment: Presumably, two people are finding it difficult to get on with one another. _I don't see a way_ means 'there may be a way, but I can't think of one'.

Comment: Near-duplicate of your previous question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252318/is-there-any-diffrent

Comment: Related: [Is there any differences between "there is no way to do something" & "That's no way to do something"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87491/is-there-any-differences-between-there-is-no-way-to-do-something-thats-no)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry my english is not that good. 
The text from the book (It is a love story, and the love is forbidden ): 
"The thing is it never gets easier between us, and it all keeps starting again and I dont see a way to do this." 
I want to know: Is that a goodbye? 
Or does it mean: Why should I do that again?
Or does it mean: I don't want that anymore.

Comment: In that context, it means "I can't think of a way in which our relationship would be able to continue".

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps :-)

Comment: It real means: I don't want that anymore! Expressed politely?